# Give TreeViewNodes different icons based on the node's text

Tags: vb.net, treeview, icons, runtime

I am trying to change a treeview node's icon based on the induvidual node's text. For example: I want all nodes named "DWG" to display a specific image/icon, all nodes named "xls" to display another icon/image, and all remaining nodes to display no icon.

So far I've been able to add images during runtime, but I don't know how to proceed with the rest.

Comment: See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haf2a2zb(v=vs.90).aspx) for examples on how to do this.  You'll want to have this code run just after you've loaded all the nodes in the treeview.  For any node you don't want to have an image, you'll set the ImageIndex and SelectedImageIndex properties to nothing or -1 (haven't worked with stock treeview in a while, and don't have VS available right now, one of those should work)

Comment: Okay well I saw this as one of my first hits on googel but it dosnt show how to set an icon for a specific parent node by name. thats is the whole problem

Comment: There is no property that will allow you to select a node by it's text, so you'll need to iterate through the nodes, checking the text and then setting the ImageIndex and SelectedImageIndex when appropriate.  In the link I provided, there are several other How To's that will give you what you need.